# Showing that ring generated by a subset is isomorphic to a quotient ring

Tags: abstract-algebra, ring-theory, universal-property

Let $R$ be a commutative ring with $1$, $S$ a subset of $R$ and let $T$ be a subring of $R$ generated by $S$. Define $\phi: \mathbb{Z}[x_s|s \in S] \to R$ to be the algebraic extension of
\begin{equation*}
x_s \mapsto s.
\end{equation*} Then $\phi$ is a ring homomorphism with Im$(\phi)=\mathbb{Z}[S]=T$. Now denote by $I=(f_i)$ an ideal generated by some polynomials of $\mathbb{Z}[x_s|s \in S]$. Suppose we claim that $T \cong \mathbb{Z}[x_s|s \in S]/I$. We know from the First Isomorphism Theorem that Im$(\phi)\cong\mathbb{Z}[x_s|s \in S]/ker(\phi)$ and since Im$(\phi)=T$, the only thing we still have to show to conclude the claim is that $ker(\phi)=I$. Is this correct or is there a gap somewhere in my reasoning?

Comment: Why would the image of $\phi$ be $\mathbb{Z}[S]$? What if $R = \mathbb{F}_p$? Then the image is surely not that! You get the ideal $I$ simply as the kernel of your homomorphism, so it is not necessary to determine it otherwise (1st Isomorphism Theorem).

Comment: @NelliKuukeri The OP is using $\mathbb Z[S]$ to mean the subring of $R$ generated by $S$, i.e., the ring previously called $T$.  The freely generated ring is here called $\mathbb Z[x_s|s\in S]$, not $\mathbb Z[S]$.

Comment: @AndreasBlass I see. Then it makes sense.

Comment: Thanks for you help!